# Silverlight, XAML, DataGrid does not autosize, no auto scrollbars

Tags: silverlight, xaml, datagrid

Can anyone tell me why the datagrid in this example gets cut off when it grows past the bounds of the Grid.Row which contains it?  Here is the xaml and code-behind which you can use in a VS 2010 'Silverlight Application' template.  Thanks in advance.

```
<UserControl
x:Class="SilverlightApplication3.MainPage"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"
mc:Ignorable="d" >

<Grid>

    <Border>

        <Grid>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!-- header -->
            <Border Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" >
            </Border>

            <!-- employee category selection -->
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="10">
                <StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Category:" Margin="0,0,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeTypes}" SelectedItem="{Binding EmployeeType, Mode=TwoWay}" MinWidth="100" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="10" Height="2" Margin="0,10,0,0" ></Border>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>

            <!-- content -->
            <Grid Grid.Row="2">

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <!-- daily employee grid -->
                <Grid Grid.Row="0" Visibility="Visible" Margin="10">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">

                        <TextBlock Text="Category Type:" />
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding Category, Mode=TwoWay}"
                              DisplayMemberPath="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="250">
                        </ComboBox>

                        <TextBlock Text="Category Types:" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
                        <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="250" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
                            <sdk:DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="sdk:DataGridColumnHeader">
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                                </Style>
                            </sdk:DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                        </sdk:DataGrid>

                    </StackPanel>

                </Grid>

            </Grid>

            <!-- buttons -->
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,10,0,0" >

                <Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
                        Width="80" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,2,0">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="../Images/Approve24x24.png" Height="24" Width="24"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Save" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>

                <Button Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" 
                        Width="80" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="../Images/Delete24x24.png" Height="24" Width="24"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Cancel" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>

            </StackPanel>

        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

and the code-behind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace SilverlightApplication3
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

```
        List<string> testItems = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            testItems.Add(string.Format("Item Number {0}", i.ToString()));
        }

        this.dataGrid.ItemsSource = testItems;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You used the StackPanel to display some elements and datagrid. So here datagrid is not constrained to any height, moreover the the parent grid of stackpanel's height is Auto. So there is no where you are making grid to occupy fixed size.

I modified your code with in a grid.

```
                <!-- content -->
            <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />                      
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />                     
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>  
                <!-- daily employee grid -->
                <Grid Grid.Row="0" Visibility="Visible" Margin="10">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>                     
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="Category Type:" />
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding Category, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          DisplayMemberPath="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="250">
                        </ComboBox>

                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Category Types:" Margin="0,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" />
                    <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Grid.Row="2" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="10"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" MinWidth="250" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
                        <sdk:DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="sdk:DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                            </Style>
                        </sdk:DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                    </sdk:DataGrid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
```

This should give you the expected result.